# How to add more than one table(new sheet like Excel) of Test Data into a single .CSV file then read in Robot Framework?

Tags: excel, csv, frameworks, robotframework

I have added the test data to the .CSV file for a single test case and wanted to add new test data for another test case in the same framework. Sample xx.csv file data which I'm using for a Test Case:

```
${name};${job};

Raman;Sr Test Engineer;
```

Now, how to add a new table with the same xx.csv file data? or How to add test data the way we can add sheets in Excel? I tried it like mentioned below but getting an error;

**[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you have some code to show?

Comment: @Mathew, Let me put my question in a different way for you. I have added a table of two columns/rows data in .CSV. But now I wanted to add another set of the table to the same . CSV file. How to do that? Here nothing to do with my code actually. If add I an extra table of same .csv file I'm getting the above error message(Please refer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a new sheets to a CSV file. It's simply not possible.

Comment: How to add a new set of test data for the other test cases in a single .CSV file for the suite? @Lubos Jerabek